# PHP curl POST for Watson Video Enrichment

Tags: php, curl, ibm-watson, php-curl

Am trying to use PHP 7.2 to submit a new job to the Watson Video Enrichment API.
**Here's my code:**

```
//set some vars for all tasks
$apiUrl = 'https://api-dal.watsonmedia.ibm.com/video-enrichment/v2';
$apiKey =  'xxxxxxxx';

//vars for this task
$path = '/jobs';
$name = 'Test1';
$notification_url = 'https://example.com/notification.php';
$url = 'https://example.com/video.mp4';
$data = array(
    "name" => $name, 
    "notification_url" => $notification_url, 
    "preset" => "simple.custom-model",
    "upload" => array(
        "url" => $url
    )
);
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl.$path );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
    'Authorization: APIKey '.$apiKey
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

But I can't get it to work, even with varying CURLOPTs, **like:**

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
```

**I keep getting the response:** `Bad Request.`

Here's the API [docs](https://ui-dal.watsonmedia.ibm.com/public/docs/api-enrichment.html#_api-post_jobs).

Am I setting up the POST CURL all wrong? Is my $data array wrong? Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What does `$apiUrl.$path` mean? please, tell me, why aren't you just using `$apiUrl` ?

Comment: If I am reading that documentation right, there is only one parameter for this endpoint, named `body`. The fields `name`, `notification_url` etc. need to be supplied as properties of that body, not be send on their own.

Comment: $apiUrl.$path is a concatenation of the 2 string variables - am using it that way as $path changes based on the task being done, so that the $apiUrl string isn't repeated for each task

Comment: @misorude they are sent together as a single json string $data_string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. Thanks to @TheGentleman for pointing the way.

My data array should look like:

```
$data = array(
    "name" => $name, 
    "notification_url" => $notification_url, 
    "preset" => array(
        "simple.custom-model" => array(
            "video_url" => $url,
            "language" => "en-US"
        )
    ),
    "upload" => array(
        "url" => $url
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading their API documentation, it looks like the field `preset` is not of type string. Rather it has a schema defined [here](https://ui-dal.watsonmedia.ibm.com/public/docs/api-enrichment.html#_api-preset).  This appears similar to how you are using the `upload` schema.

You should change your data array to look like this:

```
$data = array(
    "name" => $name, 
    "notification_url" => $notification_url, 
    "preset" => array(
        "video_url" => "https://example.com/path/to/your/video"
    ),
    "upload" => array(
        "url" => $url
    )
);
```

Comment: I think we're getting somewhere - using your change returns ```Preset not supported```

But you've opened my eyes to the other sections of the docs - I'll keep digging in there - thanks!